# Efficient low latency stream forwarding in intel atom

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

I have a certain problem in forwarding a stream from a web camera to my local network.

My Network camera provides a RTP video stream 720p24 to NIC1 of my Gateway PC (Intel Atom, 1.8GHz , Ubuntu 16.04). Now I would like to forward this stream to all PCs (Intel i5, i7,...) which are connected to NIC2 of the Gateway PC.

I tested already some stuff with ffmpeg and VLC. VLC does not even run the Video on the Atom due to Hardware limitatons and ffmpeg is just capable of 1-2fps at 480p, but ffserver works fine. MPlayer at least Shows the Video in all its beauty but does not support Streaming unfortunately.

Does anybody know a well performing way to get access to the stream of the camera through the Gateway PC without directly connecting the two Networks? Due to the fact that we would like to make some remote operations there may not be introduced any further latency for buffering, transcoding, ...

If the Solutions uses multicast I would be happy.

I really look forward to your responses!

Comment: You can pull the stream from the camera and forward it over UDP/RTP using ffmpeg. This takes up no noticeable overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your advice: this works for me now:
ffmpeg.exe -re -i input -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts "udp://239.101.101.1:12345?ttl=1&pkt_size=1316"

but I get in total approx 1000ms of delay on the whole chain. Is there a way to reduce this somehow? VLC as decoder is set to 100ms buffer